# Hard Drive goes uninitialized in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows

Physical Hard Drive is shown "uninitialized" in windows server 2008 even after reboot and I am not able to initialize the disk using Disk Manager or DiskPart.

Any solution for windows server 2008. There is a hotfix 840781 addresses the issue specifically for windows server 2003. Is there a similar hotfix available for windows server 2008?

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Do you have any RAID configuration in your server?

Comment: @akluth : NO RAID Configured.. Few  Drives are inserted into the Dell Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any hotfix addressing this issue for windows 2008. However, I have jut updated my windows (Control Panel >> Windows Updates >> Install Updates) and issue is resolved for now.. I am not sure if this will arise in future...